# Sqlite and query

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I am an android beginner. I'm trying to search whole database and find out if an "incoming" number is in a database or not and if it does exist return true if not return false,

My code for searching is included below, however it always return true even if I call it with a number that doesn't exist in the database.

In addition Should I use LIKE for searching because sometimes the incoming number is within the code of city for example **0060**172214866 or 0172214866, .(type of incomingnumber is String )

thanks in advance and sorry for any poor use of English

```
 public boolean searchnumber(String incomiingnumber) {
      boolean isit = false;
      Cursor c=ourdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] 
         {ROW_ID,KEY_NUMBER,N_NAME},
              KEY_NUMBER + "=" + incomiingnumber
      ,null,null,null,null );
           if (c != null){
          while(c.moveToNext())           
      isit= true;  }
      else 
     {
      isit=false;
      Log.v(incomiingnumber, "IS NOT it");
     } 
     return isit;
  }
```

Comment: Try to Use moveToFirst()... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using like, then using the minimum sequence you need to compare. 
Try this:

```
public boolean searchnumber(String incomiingnumber) {
String args[] = { "%" + incomingnumber + "%" };
    Cursor c = ourdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { ROW_ID,
            KEY_NUMBER, N_NAME }, KEY_NUMBER + " LIKE ?", args,
            null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        try {
            c.getString(1);
            c.close();
            return true;
        } catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            c.close();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use movetofirst() after your query 
and no its not necessary to use Like Statement it returns complete match of your strings